# Using SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services Convert Excel And PowerPoint

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2010, converters

Is there a way to convert Excel or PowerPoint Files with SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services?

Currently we can convert word files using something like this

```
ConversionJob pdfJob = new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services");
pdfJob.Name = "Mortgage Report";
pdfJob.UserToken = myWebsite.CurrentUser.UserToken;
pdfJob.AddFile(outputWordFilename, outputWordFilename.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"));
pdfJob.Start();
```

Or its a way to convert Excel or PowerPoint to Word, and the use the same code?

Comment: Xavier, Did you fixed your problem? I am busy with the same issue right now. Karens

Comment: Karens, 

With SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services, i could not get the solution, want i did was using the Interop classes to convert the files myself.

Theres Also some dll that can help you, but at the end it was easier just using the interop. 

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Xavier,

I would like to implement that feature. Can you give me some details how you implemented it?

Thanx in advance,
Karens

Comment: Have the same problem :-/ Anyone fixed the problem? Btw. in SharePoint 2013 there will be "PowerPoint Automation Services"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179894(v=office.15).aspx Björn

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519529.aspx) what you are trying to accomplish?

It may not fit 100% for you, but I had used that for one of my projects.

Comment: It could work, it something different for my code, but i will try to use interop clases to do this. Thanks in advance